# Propagating headers incoming to service mesh throughout the cluster

Tags: kubernetes, microservices, istio, distributed-tracing

I have set up an `istio`-enabled microservices architecture on a `kubernetes` cluster.

My `istio-ingressgateway` is proxied by Cloudflare.

The later, generates a of specific header, namely `cf-ray` to support troubleshooting cloudflare-related issues.

My question is how to enable my service mesh i.e. both in the edge (the `istio-ingressgateway` that is) and all sidecars to propagate the `cf-ray` id header.

`istio`'s documentation on `VirtualService` resource, in the [section](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/virtual-service/#Headers-HeaderOperations) about `HeaderOperations`, lists 3 available actions, namely `set`, `add` and `remove`.

`add` and `remove` seem to be the more unrelated to the action I want to perform, however `set` also seems to ask for a specific value to be set.

I just want a passthrough/propagation type of operation where `istio` upon seeing a `cf-ray` header, will pass it

a) in the cluster (when its about the ingress gateway)

b) from each sidecar to the main container (it goes without saying that in this case, it then becomes a responsibility of the main container's app to continue propagation from that point on)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have the problem of the sidecars propagating the headers, because the sidecars do it by default. It's like when you have to configure tracing in Istio. You just generate and propagate some headers, and no need to do anything with the sidecars.

About the generation part, actually the field you want to use is `add`. `set` will change the header value by something else (e.g. you have a `set` for `foo: bar`, if you get a request with `foo: baz`, it will set to `foo: bar`). `add`, on the other hand, will add `cf-ray` to your requests.

About the part of how to get the request into the cluster, there should be no problems as at the edge, through `Gateway` you don't configure headers. So, it will just pass through to the service.

**EXAMPLE**

```
...
spec:
  hosts:
  - service.namespace.svc.cluster.local
  http:
  - headers:
      request:
        add:
          key: "value"
    route:
    - destination:
        host: service.namespace.svc.cluster.local
...
```

Comment: The problem is that the documentation (at least imo) is kind of misleading; I just want to instruct `istio`: if you see `cf-ray` header, just pass it along; however, the docs say I __explicitly__ need to set the value with the `add` option: `    `add map<string, string> 
Append the given values to the headers specified by keys (will create a comma-separated list of values)`. Shouldn't we just be required to provide the header name that we want propagated? what is the case with those `values` there...?

Comment: I am not getting your question. Istio's documentation are not the best though. But I have tested absolutely all Istio features, and the `add` and `set` have tested myself too.

Comment: would it be possible (if and when you find some time) to update your answer with how the `VirtualService` yaml section should be structured so that `cd-rayid` is propagated?

Comment: @pkaramol I added an example. so, for the requests to `server` service the header `key: value` will be added. replace it by your header.